# TortoiseGit not showing icon overlays correctly

Tags: tortoisegit

I have a fresh repo, cloned from our gerrit box.  When I check out the normal development "master" branch (named "development"), all of the icon overlays work properly.

The problem arises when, on that fresh clone, I check out another branch "development_test".  After checking out that branch, the icon overlay shows all files as being unversioned.  If I checkout the master branch, all is well once again.  Doesn't appear to be the underscore as other branches can be checked out without issue.  Running git status or using tortoise's "check for modifications" shows no changes.

Is there some setting, someplace, either on my system or on the remote, which would cause tortoise to think the tree was different enough to be considered unversioned?

**Edit**: I have tried to increase the max cached icons limit to over 10k, no change.  Tried renaming the overlay key entries in the registry from "  TortoiseX---" to "  XTortoise---", also with no change.  The problem seems to be confined to this one branch.

Running git for windows 2.7.1.2 and TortoiseGit 1.8.16.0, both 64-bit.

Comment: Why not ask the TortoiseGit developers directly or file an issue https://tortoisegit.org/issues/? - When you checkout the other branch, do you get any errors can you provide the repository you cloned?

Comment: Cannot provide the repo.  There were no errors I could see... the checkout appears fine (with the exception of one file, which had a trailing "." [was created on linux], which I ended up putting into the .gitignore file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated in you comment one file ends with a dot, thus, TortoiseGit namely TGitCache which is responsible for calculating the file statuses fails to load the index (libgit2 reports an error if an entry in the index is not valid) and therefore all files will be displayed as added.

Fix the invalid filename and everything should work.

Comment: Yup... that ONE bad file made the whole thing fail.  I had no idea the tortoise lib was that sensitive.

Comment: This strict behavior comes from libgit2: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/3588